# Overleaf v2 saving versions?

Tags: overleaf

In overleaf v1 there was an option called 'history and revisions' where you could save different versions of the same file. Overleaf v2 however seems to not have this feature. There is a 'history' button, but I have no idea how to save the current version there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Ok I found out how to do it. Press the 'history' button on the top right corner. A panel appears on the right side. Switch the button on the top from 'labels' to 'all history'. Now on the top left corner of the editor a button called 'label this version appears'.

Make sure to `view a single version` not comparing other versions.
[image]

Comment: You can also accept your own answer. This will mark your question as resolved

Comment: I still can't see it :S

Comment: I don't see the "Label this version" option

Comment: Thanks, I think they should make it easier to find.

Comment: @Michel Gokan Click on "View single version" first, then it'll appear ;)